# ODATA - Use an OData batch GET then DELETE from the returned results

Tags: odata, batch-processing

I'm trying to compose an OData batch to retrieve a set of results from table PAYMENT using request_id for the retrieval.  From the returned results I want to extract the payment_id and add this to the URL for the delete as payment_id is the only allowed unique key in the delete URL.

**I have the below OData batch:**

--batch_ABC
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changesetPQR

--changesetPQR
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 1

GET https://XXXX-dev.corporate.ifs.com/FSMDEV/odata/payment?$filter=request_id eq '991' HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

--changesetPQR
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 2

DELETE https://XXXX-dev.corporate.ifs.com/FSMDEV/odata/payment?$filter=request_id eq '991' HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

--changesetPQR--
--batch_ABC—

**Below are the results:**

--batchresponse_fdffc443-4f7c-4be7-bbb6-4804476baa4d
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
OData-Version: 4.0

{"@odata.context":"https://XXXX-dev.corporate.ifs.com/FSMDEV/OData/$metadata#PAYMENT","value":[{"created_by":"METRIX","created_dttm":"2023-07-14T17:55:25.9100000","memo":"INTEGRATION TEST","modified_by":"METRIX","modified_dttm":"2023-07-14T17:55:25.9100000","payment_amount":"200.00","payment_card_cvv_mask":"999","payment_card_expired":"12/2024","payment_card_holder":"Joe Bloggs","payment_card_no_mask":"1234 5678 9101 1121","payment_card_type":"VISA","payment_currency":"TRY","payment_id":15,"payment_method":"CRDC","payment_ref":"INTEGRATION","payment_status":"INT","place_id":"311","request_id":"991"}]}
--batchresponse_fdffc443-4f7c-4be7-bbb6-4804476baa4d
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
OData-Version: 4.0

{"error":{"code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://XXXX-dev.corporate.ifs.com/FSMDEV/odata/payment?$filter=request_id eq '991''."}}
--batchresponse_fdffc443-4f7c-4be7-bbb6-4804476baa4d--

Is the above possible?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

I have played around a little bit with XPath as well but have been unsuccessful thus far, though it may just be my syntax that is out.  I'm also looking into maybe using a different changeset, but I can't quite join everything together.